# comparison of attributes in active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In my rails app, I have two models Student and StudentRecord. 
    student.rb
      has_many :student_records

in student_records_controller I would like to search for all records of all students that much query parameters. two of the attributes of student record are date_recorded and status.

So, in one particular search I would like to get the latest record of a student with status 'fail' but only if there is no 'pass' record after it.

```
scope = StudentRecord.join(:student)
      .
      .
      .
#so a query something like the following
scope.where("status = ?", params[:search][:status]).having ....
```

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

@Tiamon is it possible to filter in memory after retrieving the records from the database?
Is so, you might be able to do it this way:

*probably needs further optimisation*

`student_records = StudentRecord.join(:student).order('students_records.date_recorded')`

`found_records = student_records.each_with_index do |student_record, index|
  if student_record.state == 'fail'
   if ((student_records[index + 1] && student_records[index +1].state != 'pass') || !student_records[index + 1])
     student_record
   end
  end`

Comment: This will include all students who ever failed anything

Comment: It was indicated that the record belongs to a specific user `I would like to get the latest record of a student`